# Filtering by Date (linq)

Tags: linq, datetime

I have DateTime field named "repeat" in database. I want to take only records which Date in "repeat" is today.

I tried :

```
(...).Where(e => e.repeat.Value.Date.Day.Equals(DateTime.Now.Day));
```

or:

```
(...).Where(e => e.repeat.Value.Date.Day==DateTime.Now.Day);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks,Kamil

Comment: @Kamil: If any of these have helped you please mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It doesn't work" is pretty vague, but currently you're checking the *day of the week* rather than the date. I would suggest using:

```
Date today = DateTime.Today;

var query = ....Where(e => e.repeat.Value.Date == today);
```

EDIT: It's not clear what the types involved here are - if `repeat.Value` is not itself a `DateTime`, you may want:

```
var query = ....Where(e => e.repeat.Value.Date.Date == today);
```

Comment: And if `repeat.Value.Date` contains a time different of midnight?

Comment: @ArnaudF.: What do you mean by "a time different of midnight"? I was assuming that `Value` was a `DateTime`, and thus `Value.Date` was a `DateTime` for the start of the day.

Comment: @John: In a DateTime, when comparing : "2011/01/01 00:00:00 AM" to "2011/01/01 06:00:00 AM", result will be false. Or I missing something? Nothing is the original post says that this can't happen.

Comment: @ArnaudF.: I'm using the `Date` property of the database value, and comparing that with `DateTime.Today`. The `Date` property will return midnight of the day in question.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
(...).Where(e => (e.repeat >= DateTime.Today) && (e.repeat < DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)))
```

Comment: What I like about this one is that is is robust agains nulls in e.repeat.

Comment: And it is sargable, which is probably decisive.

Answer (score 1):

Expert Solution is: Use DbFunctions.CreateDateTime() in Linq Query.

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;

var actions = await _context.Set<Your_table>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.YourColumn.Value.Year, x.YourColumn.Value.Month, x.YourColumn.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0) == date)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare short date ensures you the year/month/day are the same in one shot :

```
(...).Where(e => e.repeat.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```